# How can I reindex the results of an aggregation into another index in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation, vega-lite, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm using the 7.7.0 version of Elasticsearch. I have an aggregation query that works on the ingested data to produce the output but I am not able to re-index it.

**Data Context**

The given dataset has around 500,000 records consisting of Incoming File ID, Outgoing File ID, combination of both ID’s and the time elapsed during the transaction of both ID’s over a year. There can be multiple instances where both the File ID’s combinations (IN_OUT_ID) are repeated on different days. The aggregation query I have groups these records based on IN_OUT_ID and takes the document with the smallest Outgoing ID.
I have used top hits aggregations to get the document source but when I tried reindexing with the query given below, all of the documents are being ingested into the destination index instead of just the filtered ones.

```
POST /_reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "src-new-data",
    "aggs": {
      "groupbyID": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "IN_OUT_ID",
          "order": {
            "lowest_score": "asc"
          }
        },
        "aggs": {
          "lowest_score": {
            "min": {
              "field": "OUT_FILE_ID"
            }
          },
          "lowest_score_top_hits": {
            "top_hits": {
              "size": 1,
              "sort": [
                {
                  "OUT_FILE_ID": {
                    "order": "asc"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "dest-filter-data"
  }
}
```

I want to visualize a histogram of the elapsed time from the filtered documents. If no other approach can be used for reindexing, is there any other way I can create the visualization based on the data context given? I have tried using Vega but I am not able to access the elapsed time value from the top hits bucket aggregation.

Comment: That's not the way reindex works. Your "aggs" does nothing. You can put a query in "source" that will filter the documents that get indexed to "dest", and that's all.

What you are trying to do looks a lot like "rollups". I would look into that to see if it can do what you want.

Comment: I'll look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Rollup API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rollup-apis.html).

1. You will need to create a job, specify aggregation types and other options.
2. Then run it. You may cron it to run once if you need.
3. Then use [rollup search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rollup-search.html)